# Prevent build from creating production folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, bin

In my project, i have this kind of structure for the `bin` folder:

```
-bin
   --production
        ---module1
        ---module2
```

Is there a way to build without creating `production` folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Go to your project settings: File -> Project Structure (or Cmd-; on macOS).

And edit Modules -> Paths (tab), you can change the compile output path there.
[image]

Comment: In Java is mandatory to put packages following the same package structure: `org/mypackage/Code.java` goes to `org/mypackage/Code.class` but you can choose any root output directory, usual outputs are `bin` (default in Eclipse), `out` (default in IntelliJ), `target` (def in Maven) or `build` (def in Gradle)